# Valgrind massif produces no profile output for 7-Zip

Tags: valgrind, 7zip

I want to use valgrind massif to figure out the heap memory used by 7-Zip. When I run massif on 7-Zip, it produces no output. Here's the command.

```
valgrind --tool=massif /usr/bin/7z a filename.7z filename
```

I would expect an output file named massif.out.*pid* within the current directory but no such output is produced. I should add that, using massif on other compression tools like gzip, bzip2, compress, etc. produces a massif.out.*pid* file.

I also used `valgrind -v` and there is no helpful information there either.

Any thoughts on why this doesn't work for 7-Zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/bin/7z` is a wrapper script.

```
#! /bin/sh
exec /usr/lib/p7zip/7z "$@"
```

Try running

```
valgrind --tool=massif /usr/lib/p7zip/7z a filename.7z filename
```

instead.

Comment: Yes it works, didn't realise it was a /usr/bin/7z is a shell script. It also explains why when you do `valgrind --tool=massif 7z a filename.7z filename` it gives the error **/bin/sh: Can't open 7z**. Thanks @Mikel.

Answer (score 0):

Run with `--trace-children=yes` to trace through `exec`s